CodeDeploy blue/green ECS fargate error: Invalid arn syntax
I created ECS fargate, codebuild, codedeploy and codepipeline with terraform
but when pipeline run, it fail on CodeDeploy with following log
CodeDeploy logs
CodeDeploy input
Here is my artifact files
appspec.yml
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: "<TASK_DEFINITION>"
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "name-container"
          ContainerPort: "3000"
        PlatformVersion: "LATEST"

taskdef.json
{
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
      "FARGATE"
    ],
    "family": "name-task-def",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACC_ID:role/name-execution-role",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::ACC_ID:role/name-task-role",
    "memory": "1024",
    "cpu": "512",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "image": "ACC_ID.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/name-ecr-repo:latest",
        "name": "name-container",
        "mountPoints": [],
        "logConfiguration": {
          "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "/aws/ecs/task-name",
            "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "rails"
          },
          "logDriver": "awslogs"
        },
        "cpu": 0,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "containerPort": 3000,
            "hostPort": 3000
          }
        ],
        "environment": [],
        "environmentFiles": [
            {
              "value": "name-s3-store-envs/fe-app/.env",
              "type": "s3"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true
      }
    ]
}

main.tf
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs_service" {
  ...

  deployment_controller {
    type = CODE_DEPLOY
  }
}

resource "aws_codedeploy_app" "codedeploy_app" {
  name             = "${var.codedeploy_app.name}-codedeploy-app"
  compute_platform = "ECS"
}

resource "aws_codedeploy_deployment_group" "codedeploy_deployment_group" {
  app_name               = aws_codedeploy_app.codedeploy_app.name
  deployment_group_name  = "${var.deploy_name}-deploy-grp"
  service_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.code_deploy_role.arn
  deployment_config_name = "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"
  autoscaling_groups     = var.codedeploy_deployment_groups[0].autoscaling_groups

  deployment_style {
    deployment_type   = "BLUE_GREEN"
    deployment_option = "WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL"
  }

  auto_rollback_configuration {
    enabled = var.codedeploy_deployment_groups[0].auto_rollback_configuration
    events  = ["DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE"]
  }

  load_balancer_info {
    target_group_pair_info {
      prod_traffic_route {
        listener_arns = [aws_lb_listener.listen_443.arn]
      }
      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.target_group_blue.name
      }
      target_group {
        name = aws_lb_target_group.target_group_green.name
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  name          = "${var.codepipeline_app.name}-codepipeline"
  pipeline_type = "V2"
  role_arn      = aws_iam_role.code_pipeline_role.arn

  artifact_store {
    location = module.s3_artifact.s3_bucket_id
    type     = "S3"

  ...

  stage {
    name = "Deploy"
    action {
      name            = "Deploy-BlueGreen"
      category        = "Deploy"
      owner           = "AWS"
      provider        = "CodeDeployToECS"
      input_artifacts = ["build"]
      version          = "1"
      run_order        = "1"
      configuration = {
        ApplicationName                = aws_codedeploy_app.codedeploy_app.name
        DeploymentGroupName            = "${var.deploy_name}-deploy-grp"
        AppSpecTemplateArtifact        = "build"
        AppSpecTemplatePath            = var.codepipeline_app.app_spec_path
        TaskDefinitionTemplateArtifact = "build"
        TaskDefinitionTemplatePath     = var.codepipeline_app.task_def_path
      }
    }
  }


The strangest thing is there is no deployment, just only above logs
Deployment
Deploy grp
Could anyone please help me with this? I have been struggle with this error for hours
I have try to change, update, validate config, but nothing works

I have knew where is wrong
turn out, it has to be ARN of S3, not name of S3
        "environmentFiles": [
            {
              "value": "arn:aws:s3:::name-s3-store-envs/fe-app/.env",
              "type": "s3"
            }
        ],

